# proving the L'Hopital theorem in the $\frac{\infty}{\infty}$ case

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

supposing that the $\frac{0}{0}$case already been proven, can't it just be used to prove the $\frac{\infty}{\infty}$?

first of all  $lim_{x\rightarrow c} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=\frac{\infty}{\infty}$

can't it just be transformed to $lim_{x\rightarrow c} \frac{\frac{1}{g(x)}}{\frac{1}{f(x)}}=\frac{0}{0}$ , now being in the$\frac{0}{0}$ form can't we just apply the the hopital theorem proved before so

$lim_{x\rightarrow c} \frac{\frac{1}{g(x)}}{\frac{1}{f(x)}}=
\frac{0}{0}= lim_{x\rightarrow c} \frac{(\frac{1}{g(x)})'}{(\frac{1}{f(x)})'}= $  $lim_{x\rightarrow c} \frac{(\frac{g'(x)}{g^{2}(x)})}{(\frac{f'(x)}{f^2(x)})}$, is there a way to keep it going?

Comment: The derivative of $\frac{1}{f(x)}$ is **not** $\frac{1}{f'(x)}$, so proof is incorrect.

Comment: derivative of  $\frac{f(1)}{f(x)}$ wpuld be  $\frac{f?(1)}{f(x)^{2}}$ ?

Comment: read my other comment

Comment: sorry i'm not good at latex so i don't know of to put the ()', i'll just take a bit to fix it

Comment: i fixed now thx

Comment: Ok, now the answer to your (new) question is: definitely no. The (weaker) hypothesis and (harder) proof of L'Hopital for the $\infty/\infty$ case should convince you of it.

Comment: so the only way to proof it is with the $\epsilon \delta$ definition?

Comment: There are various formulations of ["the" proof](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27H%C3%B4pital%27s_rule#General_proof) but ultimately, how could it be else? (Incidentally, your last $=$ is correct but only because two $-$ signs cancel: beware that $(1/f)'=-f'/f^2$, not $+f'/f^2$.)